# Xcode Storyboard - Where to set UITableViewCell height

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am using Xcode 7 and I am trying to **set the height of a UITableViewCell in the storyboard** settings to have a different cell height for different devices (eg. normal and compact x regular).

I cannot find a place for these settings. Is this only possible by doing it programmatically?

Comment: have you checked out heightForRowAtIndexPath? There are loads of examples of this on SO and in tutorials

Answer (score 13):

### Click on Table View after that click on Size Inspector

***and adjust your cell row height here -***

[image]

---

#### Add this below code in your controller class `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0 // Adjust Primary table height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension //This line adjust cell height according to containts
```

---

#### Swift 4  or later

- You need to change from `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to `UITableView.automaticDimension`

---

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0 // Adjust Primary table height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Comment: Hi. I could not figure out how to maintain different values for different device sizes (ex. you can maintain different font sizes or other contraints for different device sizes and/or orientations) but I could not find a way to do this via storyboard editor. The Row How as described by you seems to set it only global for all layouts.

Comment: its depends on your content sizes what data you are filling inside table row. because if you give row height 200 it will fix for all device height and width will adjust automatically.

Comment: For maintain different font sizes or other contraints for different device sizes and/or orientations you can set with code font sizes for orientations you can use different font size.

Comment: Update to Swift 4:
Use `UITableView.automaticDimension` instead of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: @amirfl , I have updated the answer as per your suggestion. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the storyboard, find you table view and select the cell. You will notice a white square at the bottom middle of the cell. You can drag it to change the cell height.

[image: Change cell height]

Comment: Hi, I could not find a way to maintain it for different device sizes/orientations differently by using your suggestion.

Comment: That is the way to change the cell height. If you want to setup different heights on different devices, I suggest learning about size classes in Xcode. Essentially, they allow you to setup different views and sizes for different devices. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set UITableView height in this way.Try this code

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone &&   ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
        {
             return 97
        }
       if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
        {
            return 115
        }
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
        {
            return 135
        }
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
        {
            return 150
        }
   return 90
}
```

Comment: Hi, so what you describe is a programmatically approach. Does this mean that the cell high depending on device sizes cannot be managed using the storyboard manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can set height from user interface and to reflect your set value you need to override table view `heightForRowAt` method e.g.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 73
    }
```